# LangChain answers with OpenAI data

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I want ChatGPT answer with my own data, I'm using this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWCaANq7xKg

This is my code:

```
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
import os

# OpenAI
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'my_key'

loader = TextLoader('mydata.txt')
text = loader.load()

# Index
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])

query = 'What is StackOverflow?'
results = index.query(query)

print(results)
```

ChatGPT knows the answer:
StackOverflow is a question and answer website for programmers and developers. It allows users to ask and answer questions related to coding, software development, and technology. It also has a reputation system where users can earn points for providing helpful answers and asking good questions.

How do I set up the code to only answer if there is information in my data?

I'm trying to look if there is some parameters on the query, but I can't find it.

Comment: What prompt are you using in this example?

Comment: query = 'What is StackOverflow?'